# Building a link structure recursively in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to build the following structure recursively using Prolog

```
link(link(link(x, y), z), w)
```

while receiving the arguments in this form:

```
xyzw
```

How could I achieve this ?
I've already tried spliting my arguments using:

```
E=..[X,Args]
```

which gives me:

```
X=x;Args=[y,z,w]
```

but I can't figure out how to build the link(...,w) structure recursively.

Comment: Accept my solution, think we will both get some points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the accumulator Prolog programming pattern
to solve the problem. I am now assuming that you have the
input `xyzw` in the form of a list `[x,y,z,w]`. The accumulator

is the second argument of the predicate `links/3`:

```
links([X|L], R) :-
   links(L, X, R).

links([], X, X).
links([X|L], Y, R) :-
   links(L, link(Y,X), R).
```

Here is the result:

```
?- links([x,y,z,w], R).
R = link(link(link(x, y), z), w).
```